# Unable to locate CSS file by inspecting code

Tags: html, css

I want to change color `#00000`, but I am unable to locate a file from where this color is coming. By inspecting the code, I found that it's showing `(index):168`.

[image]

Comment: Could you give a link to the page?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It won't be in a CSS file...it will be in a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of your HTML document....probably line 168.

Comment: I've already tried this Paulie. Its a wordpress template.@Paulie_D

Comment: last resort can be to add `!important` to the style.css (although it's not recommended). But even if it's WP template, why would there be a problem to edit css in there (head style or inline css)?!

Comment: Did you try clicking on `(index):168`?

Answer (score 0):

This is inline style. Sometimes in theme option there is options to change the appearances of the site in WordPress.
So check over the theme options.
Otherwise you can override the style by giving custom class to specific element.

Comment: No, the display `footer a, ...` does not seem to indicate this is an inline style (the term "inline style" refers to styles specified using the `style` attribute directly on an HTML element). Most likely, it's inside a `<style>` tag in the HTML.